# how to write a popup window in firefox extension

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, popup, firefox-addon

I know that we can show a popup with widget or panel and the popup is around the extension icon and I know it's easy in the chrome extension development. Now I want to create a popup with javascript.

My idea is that when I click the icon button it will send a message(include the path of iframe's html page) to the content script.My code is:

```js
nbBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
       var workers = tabs.activeTab.attach({                    
           contentScriptFile: [ data.url("js/jquery-2.0.1.min.js"),
                                data.url("mycontent.js"),
                                data.url("js/tinybox2/packed.js"),
                                data.url("js/bootstrap.min.js"),
                                data.url("js/jquery.qrcode.min.js"),
                                data.url("js/2.5.3-crypto-sha1-hmac.js"),
                                data.url("js/moment.min.js"),
                                data.url("js/extension.utils.js")]
       });
       let content = encodeURIComponent(data.load("main.html"));
       let url = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + content;
       workers.postMessage(url);
    }, false);
```

Then the content script show a popup with the message.The code is like that:

```
var showBox = function(){
    if(document.getElementById(iframeId)==null){
        console.log("Creating frame...");
        TINY.box.show({iframe:popupSrc, width:lgmBoxWidth, height:lgmBoxHeight, top:window.innerHeight*0.1, animate:true});
    }
    else{
        console.log("Frame already exist.");
    }
}

self.on('message', function(message) { 
    popupSrc = message;
    showBox();
});
```

But the iframe's html page(`main.html`) doesn't show normally because the js and css link(such as `<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">` and         `<script src="js/jquery-2.0.1.min.js"></script>`) in the iframe page can't work. So what can I do to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate your question by a code sample? Are you referring to a browser action popup, or a window popup?

Comment: Sorry for that. I have updated my problem and thanks for your remind.

Comment: Why do you want to load your (trusted) extension's content in a potentially untrusted third-party? Judging by the crypto library you're loading, the extension is going to handle sensitive data. Others can craft a page to impersonate your extension, and steal data through a fake iframe. If you really want to continue with this route, you have to serialize all resources to data-URLs (this could be automated by a build script), becaause resource-URIs canoot be loaded in non-privileged pages.

Comment: Ok.Let me tell you something about my extension's work. This extension is going to save people's password to their phone and send the password which has been saved in the phone to the login web page through the extension.And the chrome extension has been done,the link is [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/logim-extension/gbfjhjobgkdfommginkkdkollgndjipa).Could tell me something about your opinion about this work? Thank you.

Comment: And I want to do the same way in Firefox and is that possible?

Comment: Can you give a better description of your extension? Of course, I could look at your extenion's source code and infer the behaviour, but that's something I'd rather not like to do, given the size of your extension's source code. And while you're at it, put the description in the CWS such that potential users can read the description and find out whether it's useful or not

Comment: The chrome extension is under testing and uses cannot search it in the store.The extension's function is something like Chrome's password-remember feature and the different is that our server don't save user's password which is keep in user's phone.When user want to sign in a saved site,he can click the icon and scan the QR-code when he open the login page,then the password saved in the phone will fill the form automatically.If user want save a new site's password,he can fill the form ,then click the icon and scan the QR-code , after that ,the password is saved in the phone.

Comment: The best non-hackish way would be using the [`panel` module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/Firefox-22/modules/sdk/panel.html) from the Add-on SDK.

Comment: Ok.I'll try it.Thanks.